# Chrome Extension - Open popup fast, then load the data with a spinner for better performance and ux

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

You may have experienced that some chrome extensions popup shown after some seconds that is a long time for it. I want to show the popup as the user clicks on the extension icon showing an spinner, then to load the data while the user is watching the spinner that means it is loading. In both approaches the user is waiting, but when he clicks on it and sees nothing, he will click on it once more however if it opens exactly the time he clicks on it and watches the spinner gives a better experience.

How can I achieve this?
What does chrome have for this purpose?

Comment: There's nothing built-in for this and there's no need because you can simply use the standard methods: DOM to display the spinner, CSS to animate it, JS for the code.

Comment: But the size of extension is big a bit, so it takes some time to pop up. I want to pop it up exactly when clicked on the icon and then show spinner and such alike.

Comment: Then make it small and load the big parts asynchronously in your JS. There are many existing ways to do it, which should be easy to find, and it depends on what exactly your code/html is doing so there's no way to answer without seeing an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: For example I want to load a library named `chart.js`. It is big a bit. So I don't want to load it when user clicks on the icon but load it after all the libraries loaded and the data fetched from the server. BTW I don't use extension functionalities but only `iframe`s. So they can be updated easily by the server and no need the users to update their extensions.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it's a classic, here's an example of a search query: [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+loading+scripts+on+demand).